# Skel js collapsed nav not working iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, skel

I'm using Skel.js and Skel-layers.js on a website I'm working on, I'm working on a modified HTML5Up template: http://html5up.net/escape-velocity

The problem I'm facing is that the collapsable navigation doesn't work on iOS (I've tried both Safari and Chrome). The collapsable nav works in every other web browser and mobile device. The original template works on iOS.

The HTML structure, and JS are the same. All the alterations within the CSS have no impact that I have found. I've been removing elements in the `style-mobile.css` and testing the alterations in the iOS Emulator on my Macbook.

The website I'm working on is http://havenlea-farms.co.uk/
When the collapsed nav icon is clicked, there is no response in iOS.

Has anyone got any ideas on what the cause could be? I'm aware that the question structure isn't great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much frustration I've found the problem. After manually unloading my stylesheets and javascript files, the problem was with an Arc Text lib I was using. https://github.com/codrops/Arctext

Once I removed the reference to the lib the navigation worked on iOS. I'll report this as a issue on GitHub for both Skel and Arctext.